# Why is useEffect cleanup function getting called on first render?

Tags: reactjs

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // setState(1)
      console.log("inside cleanup");
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {console.log(state)}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the console.log() inside of cleanup is getting consoled in browser. i am not sure why is this happening.As per  my concepts, cleanup should be called when the component is updating on state change and that state is a part of dependency array, or no dependency array at all

Comment: You are apparently using [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). In development builds, strict mode will mount your component, then unmount it, then mount it again. This forces you to encounter situations where the cleanup runs, and thus lets you more easily notice bugs if you aren't cleaning up correctly.

Comment: fine got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wrapping you app in `<StrictMode>` your components will be mounted / unmounted / remounted to identify potential unsafe lifecycles. This only occurs on developement mode.

Comment: what are examples of unsafe lifecycle

Comment: you have everything in the documentation @nicholas shared :)
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#identifying-unsafe-lifecycles

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` cleanup function does not only run when our component wants to unmount, it also runs right before the execution of the next scheduled effect.

In fact, after `useEffect` executes, the next scheduled effect is usually based on the dependency(array).

In `strict` mode, development build, `useEffect` is executed twice. So a cleanup is run post the next scheduled effect. From react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

> effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
```

All the code here is getting called only once

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // setState(1)
      console.log("inside cleanup");
    };
  }, []);
```

All the code here is getting called on every state update, on first render or when its parent is updated

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {console.log(state)}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

}